# Return statements acting weird in "if" statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, return

My question is regarding this **statement** I read online that went something along the lines of "lines that follow the 'if statement' and are at the same indentation as the "if statement" will always run, regardless whether the 'if statement' is true or false." I'll show that using my examples below.

So I have this procedure that takes in two numbers as inputs and returns the greater of the two inputs.

Therefore, the 4th and 5th lines of code in this first example, which are at the same level of indentation as "if a>b:" should always run according to the statement above.

Example #1

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a>b:
        x = "the first number is bigger"
    x = "the second number is bigger"
    return x
print bigger(9,7)
```

Python prints "the second number is bigger," so the code is working according to that original statement I wrote in the beginning. Even though that is false because 9>7.

But where I run into confusion is when return statements are used in the following example:

Example #2

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return "the first number is bigger"
    return "the second number is bigger"
print bigger(9,7)
```

This time, Python prints "the first number is bigger." This is true because 9>7

My confusion: Shouldn't the 4th line of code in this second example, "return "the second number is bigger"", always run because it's at the same indentation level of the "if statement," just like we saw in example #1?

It seems like the two examples of code contradict each other because in the example #1, Python recognizes the "second number is bigger" line and prints that line but in example #2, Python ignores the "second number is bigger" line and prints the other "first number is bigger" line.

I tried to make this as clear as possible. Thanks

Comment: Nothing weird about it. By design return returns from the function immediately in Python.

Comment: @paisanco Thanks. I never knew that returns returned immediately. I assumed it didn't return immediately, so of course I was confused. The more you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My confusion: Shouldn't the 4th line of code in this second example,
>   "return "the second number is bigger"", always run because it's at the
>   same indentation level of the "if statement," just like we saw in
>   example #1?

This is because the function execution breaks when you have a return statement:

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return "the first number is bigger" # function execution breaks here!!!
    return "the second number is bigger"
print bigger(9,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read a little a bit about function and what return means. 
Very briefly, if a return statement is executed the function goes out of scope and will not run anything after it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, first it compares two values `9` and `7`, then x = `the first number is bigger`, then it assigns `x= the second number is bigger` and return `x`. It is why you see this line.

In second example, it also compare two values, but it return x immediately, so it doesn't go the the next lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "statement that you read" was a bit too simplistic. It is correct only if nothing changes Python's normal control flow during the `if` statement or the following indented block. It doesn't apply if the control flow is changed, which is exactly what you're doing in your second example. A `return` statement does change the control flow, to make the function exit immediately, so the rest of the code after the `if` does not get run.

Other statements that change the control flow are `raise` (and invalid operations that cause exceptions to be raised without an explicit `raise` statement), `break` and `continue`. The latter two are only valid in loops.