# Why If Statement isn't running even if conditions are met?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to create a Boiling Point and Freezing Point Depression Calculator in Python. I was trying to create the logic that would determine if the program would use the Boiling Point Elevation Equation or to use the Freezing Point Elevation based on user input. However the if statement does not print the statement even if those conditions are met. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def determine_boiling_point_equation():    
if (calculations == "Boiling"):
    Boiling = True
    return Boiling
    print("This works")
```

Calculation asks the user to type in "Boiling" string if you want to calculate boiling point equation or "Freezing" string if you want to calculate freezing point equation

Comment: Realistically, it's going to be very difficult for people to tell you why code you haven't shown isn't working - please [edit] to include a [mcve]. But I'd guess it's misuse/misunderstanding of `and` and `or`, or the type of the `input`.

Comment: A function *ends* when it returns.

Comment: How do I post my code into the question?

Comment: You might get your expected output if you move the `print("This works")` statement above `return Boiling`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return statements acting weird in "if" statements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386936/return-statements-acting-weird-in-if-statements-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to give the function input for `calculations`.
2. There is no tab for the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def determine_boiling_point_equation(calculations):   
    if (calculations == "Boiling"):
        Boiling = True
        return Boiling
        print("This works")
```